# Sync Dirty Flags using SQLite Trigger

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I am trying to sync dirty flag between two tables.  A form can have several Answers associated with it.  If any of those answers are ever marked dirty, I would like the form to also be marked dirty.  Below is what I am currently trying, doesn't seem to work.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS markFormDirtyIfAnswerDirty AFTER UPDATE ON Answer WHEN isDirty=true " +
            "BEGIN " +
            "UPDATE Form SET dirty=true WHERE _id=OLD.formId; " +
            "END ");
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myappmobile.test/com.myapp.myappmobile.activities.DashboardActivity_}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
```

Comment: Thank you for keeping the error message a secret.

Comment: Oop sorry.  I added it to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  Turns out SQLite doesn't support true and false instead you have to use 1 and 0.  Also I Needed to use the NEW reference when checking the dirty flag.  The correct response looks like the below.

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS markFormDirtyIfAnswerDirty AFTER UPDATE ON Answer WHEN NEW.isDirty=1 " +
            "BEGIN " +
            "UPDATE Form SET dirty=1 WHERE _id=OLD.formId; " +
            "END ");
```